# Incorporating ISNULL into a CASE expression

Tags: sql-server-2008, isnull

I have the following `CASE` expression and the `ISNULL` portion is not registering:

```
CASE WHEN IsNull(2010) THEN 0 END) * 
CASE WHEN IsNumeric([Dur_In_Hours]) = 1 THEN 
  CAST([Dur_In_Hours] AS FLOAT) ELSE 0 END) AS Cost
```

Comment: Also it is always useful to explain what things like "not registering" mean. Do you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: Then it is a terrible column name. Not only does it start with a number (meaning it will always have to be escaped with `[square brackets]`, but it also begs for normalization, and is not descriptive in the least. It's something for the year 2010, but what?

Comment: Finally, why oh why are you storing duration in hours in a string-based column?

Comment: And why are you casting what is presumably an integer or a 2-digit decimal, multiplied by an integer, as float?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are using the `IsNull()` function wrong. If you are testing if a column is null then you will use:

```
CASE 
  WHEN 2010 is null 
  THEN 0 
END 
* 
CASE 
  WHEN IsNumeric([Dur_In_Hours]) =1 
  THEN CAST([Dur_In_Hours] AS FLOAT) 
  ELSE 0 
END AS Cost
```

If you want to use `IsNull()` then you can use `IsNull([2010], 0)` to replace that `CASE` expression:

```
IsNull([2010], 0)
* 
CASE 
  WHEN IsNumeric([Dur_In_Hours]) =1 
  THEN CAST([Dur_In_Hours] AS FLOAT) 
  ELSE 0 
END AS Cost
```

Or you can use `COALESCE` to replace the first `CASE`:

```
COALESCE([2010], 0)
* 
CASE 
  WHEN IsNumeric([Dur_In_Hours]) =1 
  THEN CAST([Dur_In_Hours] AS FLOAT) 
  ELSE 0 
END AS Cost
```

Answer (score 2):

[`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) is an expression, not a statement. It's a subtle nit-pick but [the distinction is important](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression), IMHO.

I think you meant:

```
CASE WHEN [2010] IS NULL THEN 0 END
```

But that doesn't make any sense at all unless you are hard-coding 2010 there but plan to use a variable or column name later.

[`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) is something completely different than what you are after (at least as far as I can tell). It does not work the same way as it does in Access. For that reason I *usually* recommend [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) instead, which functions similarly in most cases. I wrote this tip last year to help differentiate:

- [Deciding between COALESCE and ISNULL in SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Comment: I have it down to 'CASE WHEN [2010] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE CAST([2010] AS FLOAT)*CASE WHEN IsNumeric([Dur_In_Hours]) =1 THEN CAST([Dur_In_Hours] AS FLOAT ELSE 0 END) AS Cost' ANd I am getting Unable to Parse Query Text

Comment: @Andrew you are missing the `END` on the first `CASE` statement. You always have to have `CASE..WHEN..THEN..END`

Comment: It is all one large case statement though, I tried adding the END and it did not work

Comment: @Andrew Then you should post the full statement. Posting bits and pieces of the query will make it hard to debug. Also you should format your query, that will help you find the issues.

Comment: What tool is saying "Unable to Parse Query Text"? Maybe you should stop using that tool, I don't think it is doing you any favors. A proper query window in Management Studio with IntelliSense enabled will highlight all of these trivial and repeated syntax errors...